# The matrix A=[-2 2 1 3 ] is invertible with A^(-1)=1/8 [-3 2 1 2 ].

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ is invertible with $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{8} \begin{pmatrix}-3 & 2\\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

(TRUE/FALSE)? In my opinion the answer is True because $A^{-1}= \text{adj}( A)$ divided by $\det(A)$ gives the same answer.
    How can i provide a good justification for this?

Comment: Non-square matrices do not have an inverse, but in some cases may have a left inverse or right inverse

Comment: These are $2\times2$ matrices, right?  You can check by multiplying the two matrices.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes i would persume that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&2\\1&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-3&2\\1&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}8&0\\0&8\end{pmatrix}$$